# How to add custom transparent MKAnnotation to MKMapView?

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, calayer, mkannotationview

So I am trying to replicate the following scenario (translucent annotation views) :

[image]

And I have tried unsuccessfully the following implementations:

1- Creating a custom image with 30% opacity and adding to the map ---> Result: The image stays opaque.

Code:

```
-(id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{

self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

    LLAnnotation *myA = (LLAnnotation*) annotation;

    self.accessibilityLabel = myA.title;
    self.annotation = myA;
    self.enabled = YES;
    self.canShowCallout = YES;

    self.centerOffset = CGPointMake(5,-10);

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"];
}

return self;
```

}`

And then adding it in - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation_

2- Adding a sublayer to the AnnotationView and clearing it ---> Result: Doesn't show any annotation.

Code:

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation_
{

    if (annotation_ == mapView.userLocation) return nil;

    MKAnnotationView *m = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation_ reuseIdentifier:@"default"];

//    m.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc]init];

    layer.frame = m.frame;

    layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGreenColor].CGColor;

    [m.layer addSublayer:layer];

    m.layer.cornerRadius = m.frame.size.width/2;
    m.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    m.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    return m;
}
```

I was thinking that adding MKOverlays on top of annotations maybe a workaround but it shouldn't be the way to go I believe.

**Does anyone have other suggestions on how to implement this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `UIImageView` object and make it looks like the image you required.

Add as subview of annotationView in `viewForAnnotation` delegate method will do the trick.

Also you need to set center position offset for annotation image to render annotation exactly correct position of location.

Have look on below code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation_
{

    if (annotation_ == mapView.userLocation) return nil;

    MKAnnotationView *m = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation_ reuseIdentifier:@"default"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(m.center.x, m.center.y, 20, 20)];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.7294 green:0.7843 blue:0.1921 alpha:1.0]];

    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    imageView.alpha = 0.6f;
    [m addSubview:imageView];

    // Also set center offset for annotation  
    [m setCenterOffset:CGPointMake(-10, -20)];

    return m;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create an image in photoshop which has a transparent background, and then add your desired yellow circle on top. Then make the opacity of that circle to what ever opacity you want. Save the image as a PNG.

Once you have saved the image, add it to your Xcode project. Once you've added it, add the following line under your `viewForAnnotation`.

```
annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ThisIsThePNGImagesName.png"];
```

**Hope that helps :)**

Comment: That's exactly what I have done in the first implementation (check above) - and it didn't work.